# Domain user has different umask than expected

Tags: ldap, kerberos, pam

I have a network domain with multiple users managed by LDAP and Kerberos.

I'm managing the default umask via pam.d, in my `/etc/pam.d/common-session` with the line:

```
session optional    pam_umask.so        umask=002
```

This appears to have all users reporting `0002` as the output from `umask`, with the exception of one user. This user is in the same groups and is creating sessions the same way, but when they issue the `umask` command they get `0022`.

This is causing havoc as I have all my users sharing a common group and users are supposed to be able to run applications that share certain files (for logging etc.) and if this one particular user happens to be the creator of a file, he doesn't provide group-write permissions and subsequent users experience issues.

I'm totally stumped and looking for some ideas on what I might be missing or where I should start looking to troubleshoot.

Addendum, my systems are running Debian 10.

EDIT: I'm adding the users `~/.profile` from the system:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Does that user have an umask specified in `getent passwd USERNAME`, or if not, is their ~/.profile or some other login script overriding it?

Comment: Output from the users `getent passwd USERNAME` looks identical to mine, with the exception of the UID, and they have a default `~/.profile` (added to question) with no override of umask (it's commented out). The problem exists on another system where they don't have a `~/.profile` file as well. I'm going to do some more digging on the pam module side, as this should be controlling umask for all domain users.